# Mass spring damper calculation in Matlab using Runge Kutta

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I get always an Error: **Index exceeds matrix dimensions.**

**Error in rhs (line 13)**
        **xdot_2 = -(b/m)*x(2) - (k/m)*x(1) + force(t)/m;**

**Error in FinalProject2 (line 20)**
**result = rhs(100,x0);**

I have a mass spring damper system with this to achieve:

1. Initially releasing it is release and just once it touch the ground, to see what is it’s initial poistion. Then a force is introduced to see how much it compress and reacts. Finally this force is released to see how much time it will take to recover.
2. Calculate the potential, and kinetic energy of the system (spring gravity and mass)
   once the force is removed and until the system stops
3. Calculate the energy lost by the damping once the force is removed and until the
   system stops.
4. Get the characteristic function of damping of the damper, ie, the function describing
   the motion as it decays
5. Calculate as accurately as posible the crossing points by y (substract the initial
   compresion) of the final position y once the force is removed and until the system
   stops.

this is my code:

```
clc, close all, clear *

t_start = 0; 
t_end   = 1000;  %final time in seconds. 
t =t_start:0.001:t_end; 

k = 1500.0; % as spring constant N/m,
b = 30;  %the damping constant Ns/m,
m = 10.0; %the mass of the device,
F = 0.0; %as the input force N
g = 9.81; %as the gravity constant m/s^2


 initial_position = 0; 
 initial_speed    = 0; 

 x0 = [initial_position  initial_speed]; 

 result = rhs(100,x0);
```

with this as my rhs function:

```
function xdot=rhs(t,x) 
k = 1500.0; % as spring constant N/m,
b = 30;  %the damping constant Ns/m,
m = 10.0; %the mass of the device,
force = 0.0; %as the input force N
%g = 9.81; %as the gravity constant m/s^2

    xdot_1 = x(2); 
    xdot_2 = -(b/m)*x(2) - (k/m)*x(1) + force(t)/m; 

    xdot = [xdot_1 ; xdot_2 ]; 
end
```

so what I am doing wrong? Can someone help me by calculating those values? Would be a great help :)

EDIT: my RK function:

```
 % Classical fourth-order Runge-Kutta method
 function [t,y] = rk(yprime, tspan, y0, h)



t0 = tspan(1); tfinal = tspan(end);

% set up the t values at which we will approximate the solution
t = [t0:h:tfinal]';

% include tfinal even if h does not evenly divide tfinal-t0
if t(end)~=tfinal, t=[t tfinal]; end

m = length(t);
y = [y0 zeros(length(y0), length(t)-1)];

 for i=1:(m-1)
 k1 = feval(yprime,t(i),y(:,i));
 k2 = feval(yprime,t(i)+0.5*h, y(:,i)+(h.*k1)/2);
 k3 = feval(yprime,t(i)+0.5*h, y(:,i)+(h.*k2)/2);
 k4 = feval(yprime,t(i)+h, y(:,i)+h.*k3);

 y(:,i+1) = y(:,i)+(h*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4))/6;
 end
```

and I call it with this:

```
yprime=rk(@(t,x) rhs(t,x,force));
tspan = [0 10]; 
y0 = 0;
h = 0.1; 
[t,y] = rk(yprime, tspan, y0, h); 
figure(1), clf
plot(t,y,'b.','markersize',15);
```

Comment: Well, you defined `force` to be a scalar and then call it as a function or, more erroneously, index it like a vector with a highly likely non-integer.

Comment: @TroyHaskin yes because force is a value which is at peak 100N, so what should I do?

Comment: You need the force as a function of time.  Define it as such using an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and [parametrize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) the handle you send to your Runge-Kutta function: `rk(@(t,x) rhs(t,x,force));`.  Or whatever the syntax is since the RK function is not posted.

Comment: @TroyHaskin I just posted my Runge-Kutta function above, so it should work with your syntax I guess

Comment: well I added also in the edit how I call it and it says "not enough input arguments"

Comment: Where is the function form of `force` defined (something like `force = @(t) sin(t);`?  Is it an argument to `rhs`?  In `rhs`, `force` is still set to `0.0` and not a function.  ... The error comes from `yprime=rk(@(t,x) rhs(t,x,force));` since `rk` needs four arguments to work.

Comment: @TroyHaskin my force function is a sinus yes so what I have to change now?